# How to disable the pause button after one click and enable as soon as popup displays using angular2 and typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a timer in which pause button is there. Once I click pause, it must get disabled until popup comes and become enable as soon as popup comes. Please help me to solve this issue. I am sharing my code here:

HTML:

```
<button md-icon-button class="trackingBtn active" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Resume" [disabled]="!this.isPermission || pauseDisable" (click)='resumeTimer(currentTask)' [hidden]='play'>
                            <md-icon svgIcon="play"></md-icon>
                        </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code from the comment above using the `.finally()` operator as requested. No changes are required in the template suggested above.

Add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally'` in the beginning of your file alongside the other imports.

```
pauseTimer(currentTask) {
this.buttonDisabled = true; // <-- disable the button here
  var times = {
    "state":"pause",
    "date": new Date()
  };
  currentTask.times.push(times);
  var times_data = {
    "times":currentTask.times,
    "user_id":this.user_id,
    "company_id":JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id'))
  }
  this.ApiService
      .editEntry(currentTask._id,times_data)
      .finally(()=> {
          // Code inside this block will execute no matter if the observable fails or succeeds.
          this.buttonDisabled = false; // <-- enable the button again
      })
      .subscribe(
        entry => {
          this.play = false; 
          this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Your task timer has been paused');
          this.timerService.pauseTimer();
        },error => {
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
        })
}
```

There is not much difference between these solutions. The finally operator is good to know because it comes in handy very often especially when displaying loading indicators.

Comment: Ya, Thank you.. Can you give me solution for my updated code in question please.

Comment: I am not getting how to add extra button disabled to html code i this <button md-icon-button class="trackingBtn active" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Resume" [disabled]="!this.isPermission || pauseDisable <--" (click)='resumeTimer(currentTask)' [hidden]='play'>
                            <md-icon svgIcon="play"></md-icon>
                        </button>

Comment: No changes are required in the HTML. Keep it as suggested in the accepted reply. :)

Comment: no no.. this is for different button, the resume button already had pausedisabled i need to add extra buttondisabled to it.. i want to no how that can be used

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right you could do it like this:

You could introduce a helper variable in your component like:

```
private buttonDisabled: boolean;
```

Then disable the button with a `OR` condition like:

```
<button md-icon-button class="trackingBtn" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Pause"
[disabled]="!this.isPermission || buttonDisabled" // <--
*ngIf="play" (click)='pauseTimer(currentTask)'>
```

In your `pauseTimer()` you set it to `true` at the beginning and set to false once the function has been completed.

```
pauseTimer(currentTask) {
this.buttonDisabled = true; // <-- disable the button here
  var times = {
    "state":"pause",
    "date": new Date()
  };
  currentTask.times.push(times);
  var times_data = {
    "times":currentTask.times,
    "user_id":this.user_id,
    "company_id":JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id'))
  }
  this.ApiService
      .editEntry(currentTask._id,times_data)
      .subscribe(
        entry => {
          this.play = false; 
          this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Your task timer has been paused');
          this.buttonDisabled = false; // <-- enable the button again
          this.timerService.pauseTimer();
        },error => {
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
          this.buttonDisabled = false; // <-- enable the button again
        })
}
```

Comment: A slight bit more elegant solution will be to use the `.finally()` operator from `'rxjs/add/operator/finally'`.
`.finally(()=>{  this.buttonDisabled = false;  })`

Comment: Can u please help me to make the sameway with the updated code also

Comment: @BiserAtanasov: Can u help me how that can be written in my code.. i am very new to this so not getting how to do